# Where to get a feedback on composed baroque music?

Tags: composition, baroque-period

I am trying to write music in baroque style. Are there places (on Internet) where I could get feedback on my compositions?

Comment: I don't see how this question can be answered without you providing additional information, where in the process you are and which kind of feedback you expect. Examples are: only qualified people to provide feedback, detailed judgment bordering to coaching/tutoring intended, or just: is there a market for music like this.

Comment: There's a trick to get an answer right here: ask a specific question about definded chord in a certain bar or something about a motif and your reflections or doubts about it, poste the entre piece and mark the bar in question.  (sheet or audiofile). You will probably get a friendly answer and may be even a feedback to your composition.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because off site resource recommendations are off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any baroque music fan can provide feedback, really, and every classic musician is usually a good reference too. There is plenty of forums with classic musical as a topic in mind which I'm sure you will be able to find your general objetive.

Unfortunately, stackexchange is not meant to be a opinion based recommendation system not even for websites.

Hope it helps.